# How to fix npm ERR! peer dep missing: node-opus@^0.2.7, required by discord.js@11.5.1?

Tags: node.js, heroku, discord.js, opus

I've deployed a discord music bot to the heroku and everything works except the playing music in a voice channel, although when i've ran my code on the pc - everything worked. Typing the npm list i've saw the error message "npm ERR! peer dep missing: node-opus@^0.2.7, required by discord.js@11.5.1". The problem with node-opus and obviously bot can't play music because of this. And of course i've put this and others libraries into the package.json using npm init. I paste below a piece of code from the package.json file.

I've tried to install all this libraries with npm, yarn, npm and yarn with package.json.

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "discord.js": "^11.5.1",
    "ffmpeg-binaries": "^4.0.0",
    "google-tts-api": "0.0.4",
    "heroku": "^7.25.0",
    "node-gyp": "^5.0.0",
    "node-opus": "^0.3.2",
    "simple-youtube-api": "^5.2.0",
    "sqlite3": "^4.0.9",
    "uws": "^10.148.1",
    "ytdl-core": "^0.29.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node bot",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would delete the `node_modules` folder, run `npm i -g install-peerdeps` after installing discord.js and then run `install-peerdeps discord.js@11.5.1` in your project folder if none of the other peer dependencies screw with it. If they do, you can always just `npm rm <module>` away.

Answer (score 0):

Quoted from the [Discord.js docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome)...

> Ignore any warnings about unmet peer dependencies, as they're all optional.

So, unless the message appears in the console when you try to use `node-opus`, don't worry about the warning.

Since your issue is with voice support, take these steps in an attempt to reach a solution.

- Ensure that FFmpeg is installed and working in your Heroku environment: see [this buildpack](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/jonathanong/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg-latest).
- Although you have `node-opus` installed, try the specific version Discord.js wants: `npm i node-opus@^0.2.7`.
- If `node-opus` isn't working at all, try `opusscript` (although `node-opus` is perferred).

Comment: I've tried to do this, but i still have a problem with playing music into voice channel. I've installed the `opusscript`, removed the `node-opus` and installed `ffmpeg` library by your link. Looks like the problem is not with `opus`. At least i don't have an error in `npm list` any more. Any ideas how to solve the problem? May be i've installed `ffmpeg` somehow not properly?

Comment: Is there an error in your console when the streaming doesn't work?

Comment: No, there isn't. But i saw `NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error` when the bot was deploying into heroku in build logs. May be the problem with this?